# How can i make a path file in php

Tags: php

I was wondering how can I make an path file in php? 
For example I would like to have a pointer file in the root folder that points to the folder where the php script are held.

I tried something like this, but it does not work.

path.php (is in the root file eg. htdocs/project1/week5)

```
$path = "/project1/week5/php";

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

alert.php (is in the root file eg. htdocs/project1/week5)

```
include("path.php");
include("AlertFormAction.php");
```

AlertFormAction.php (is in  htdocs/project1/week5/php)

What am I doing wrong? Could somebody be so kind and show me how it is supposed to be done? Thank you.

Comment: *"it does not work"* does not says much. Are you getting an error message? If not, please enable error reporting/display and/or check your PHP error log for the message. The message would be helpful to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$path` variable contains an absolute path that in most likelihood, does not exist.

Paths in PHP are local (to the server) filesystem paths. At a guess, I'd say you want to try

```
$path = '/htdocs/project1/week5/php';
```

As the include path "php" seems to be relative to your `path.php` file, you may find this more flexible

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    __DIR__ . '/php',
    get_include_path()
)));
```

If using PHP 5.2 or lower, replace `__DIR__` with `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: @hakre Unless I'm using PEAR or some other system-wide library, I usually drop the default include path. PHP's FIFO include path search really benefits from a short stack